# Is there a faster method for insert into Cassandra

Tags: c#, cassandra

I am receiving several 1000 messages per second which I should like to store in Cassandra in timeorder ASAP.

Currently, for each message I create a string and then call execute:

```
       string cmd = @"INSERT INTO tick_store.""MY_Data""
                            (""SeqNum"", ""AskPrice"", ""AskSize"", ""MY_Complete_Code"", ""BidPrice"", ""BidSize"", ""LastPrice"", ""LastSize"", ""RecordType"", ""Volume"", ""utcDT"")
                            VALUES(" + ++CqlSeqNum + @", " + AskPrice + @", " + AskSize + @", '" + MY_Complete_Code + @"', " + BidPrice + @", " + BidSize + @", "
                             //        + LastPrice + @", " + LastSize + @", '" + RecordType + @"', " + Volume + @", " + ToUnixTimestamp(utcDT) + @") ";
        +LastPrice + @", " + LastSize + @", '" + RecordType + @"', " + Volume + @", '" + utcDT.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff") + @"') ";

        CqlSession.Execute(cmd);
```

The blockage is on the ".Execute" line. When I comment it out the performance is fine.

For reference, I am able to write "cmd" to disk without any performance problems.

What could I try to speed up the insert?

Answer (score 1):

I don't specifically know the C# driver, but you are getting a performance hit because it seems you are using *synchronous* execute statements. If you want to maximize insert performance you should go the *asynchronous* route with **ExecuteAsync**. Moreover, please consider using prepared statements, they can give a small performance boost.